# SQL Practice easy task

Tags: sql

TASK:

Select list of the release years and the number of movies released in each year from movies table.

Use function COUNT(*) for a new column num_movies to store the number of movies in the result table.

if I understand right I do something like this to get the amount in each year

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM movies
GROUP BY release_year
```

But I don't understand how to get release_year and num_movies as a result

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`.

Comment: On your next question, please do not use thing like: "_I tried everything, doesn't work_". You should/could SHOW what you tried, and explain why it **doesnot work**, or what your expectations are.

Comment: *I tried everything, doesn't work* - please include this in your question and exactly what is not working - any error etc.

Comment: @Luuk okay I won't

Answer (score 2):

Since I assume you are only starting out with SQL, I'll also provide you with a fiddle example - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tTYdm8uQ4U5h31QUS49xfS/2.

`GROUP BY` is a clause used with the `COUNT()` function to organize and group the results based on unique values in a specific column, allowing you to count occurrences within each group.

Since you want to get occurrences based on release year, you need to group by that particular column as well.

```
SELECT release_year, count(*) as num_movies 
FROM movies
group by release_year;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT release_year, COUNT(*) AS num_movies
FROM movies
GROUP BY release_year;
```

You can try this , hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Consider an example

```
movies
+----+------------------+-------------------+
| ID | Title            | Release_Year      |
+----+------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | Movie1           | 2020              |
| 2  | Movie2           | 2020              |
| 3  | Movie3           | 2021              |
| 4  | Movie4           | 2021              |
| 5  | Movie5           | 2022              |
| 6  | Movie6           | 2022              |
| 7  | Movie7           | 2022              |
+----+------------------+-------------------+
```

To get list of the release years and the number of movies released in each year from movies table.

```
Query:

SELECT release_year, COUNT(*) AS num_movies
FROM movies
GROUP BY release_year;
```

```
Output: 
+--------------+-------------+
| release_year | num_movies  |
+--------------+-------------+
| 2020         | 2           |
| 2021         | 2           |
| 2022         | 3           |
+--------------+-------------+
```